# Auto close Torrent on open VPN

Tags: scripts, vpn, qbittorrent

I'm newbie on Ubuntu and use a lot of torrent to download a lot multimidia content.

Is there a way to auto close a program like torrent when I turn on the VPN client? And When I turn off the VPN client open the torrent again?

Comment: Not sure about auto closing/starting programs with a VPN but you could permanently run a VPN but use use "cgroups" (Linux Control Groups) to run certain programs which then specifically bypass the VPN while everything else uses the VPN. I can elaborate if that's of any use, just start your comment with `@codlord ` so I see it.

Comment: Are you sure that is what you want?  Most people think a torrent program should only run with a VPN on, not off.  Some torrent clients do have option to only received/send when Tun0(VPN) network is working.

Comment: @codlord can you explain more of this "cgroups"? I think it works for me

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is an example of using cgroups to have certain processes bypass your VPN.

Install required tools:
`sudo apt-get install cgroup-lite cgroup-tools`

Then on each bootup where I want this functionality I do this in a terminal shell:

```
sudo su
./cgroup_setup.bash
exit
```

Where cgroup_setup contains something like this (change myuser, mynetworkdevice and mygatewayip as appropriate):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define a control group named novpn with a classid of 11:11
sudo cgcreate -a $USER:$USER -t $USER:$USER -g net_cls:novpn
echo 0x00110011 > /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/novpn/net_cls.classid

# Change ownership so myuser can run processes bypassing the vpn
sudo chown myuser:myuser /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/novpn
sudo chown myuser:myuser /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls/novpn/*

# Add mark 11 on packets of classid 0x00110011
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -j MARK --set-mark 11

# Force the packets to exit through my interface (mynetworkdevice) with NAT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m cgroup --cgroup 0x00110011 -o mynetworkdevice -j MASQUERADE

# Define a new "novpn" routing table
# This is persistent so it does not actually need to be done each time in script...
echo 11 novpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

# Packets with mark 11 will use novpn
ip rule add fwmark 11 table novpn

# Add a route for default gateway for novpn
ip route add default via mygatewayip table novpn

# Unset reverse path filtering for all interfaces
for i in /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter; do echo 0 > $i; done

# Create control group
cgcreate -t $USER:$USER -a $USER:$USER -g net_cls:novpn
```

Now you can use cgexec to run a process bypassing the VPN for example:

```
killall firefox
cgexec -g net_cls:novpn firefox
```

If you run firefox normally with a VPN running you should see that your public facing IP is a VPN IP. But with cgexec bypassing the VPN you can check it's your actual home IP.